# infrastructure for secure network monitoring

Tags: networking, router, security, monitoring, network-monitoring

Assume I have some standard dsl router and a pc, which is connected through the router with the internet. Also suppose both are compromised with rootkits placed in the flash storage of those machines.

How can I monitor the network traffic of both machines (i.e. I don't want to monitor the network traffic at the host machine it self)? I need some solution / infrastructure, where another device just observes the traffic and is invisible for the other machines.

Comment: This an actual problem you actually face or just a really bad hypothetical situation?

Comment: You shouldn't trust your ISPs router anyways. Run your own behind it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Managed Ethernet switches often include a port mirroring (sometimes called port spanning) feature to allow all traffic to/from a given port to be mirrored to another port so you can hook up a packet sniffer to the second port and analyze everything that’s going on.

I’ve even seen decently cheap ( <$100) 5- and 8-port managed switches with this feature.

If you want to monitor what’s going on upstream of the DSL modem, it gets trickier. I imagine you’d need to buy your own DSLAM (that’s the box at the phone company’s end of your DSL line).

Comment: Unless you separate the "IP router" and the "DSL modem" into two devices, connected via Ethernet.

Comment: I highly recommend checking out ntop-ng, which is a Linux based packet capture/analysis tool with a nice web interface.  You will still need to setup port mirroring (sometimes called SPAN on Cisco switches).  I use it at work to monitor our LAN that spans several subnets/VLANs and it works like a charm

Comment: @Spiff, are there exists EuroDOCSIS 3.0 cable modems where I can lock all writeable flash memory or at least the memory is only writeable over specific hardware port. So that it is not possible to hack the modem since write protection is enable? And by write protection I mean a protection which is also hardware controlled via jumper or a special port.